# Sockets in Java - How can I write to DataOutputStream to a specific client?

Tags: java, sockets

I have implemented a chat using Client-Server model in Java. However, I have this one problem with `dos.writeUTF(msgout)` where dos is a DataOutputStream object.

Let's say Client 1 and Client 2 connect to the Server. Server is able to handle messages from both clients in its DataInputStream. However, when writing back, the server will only send the message to the **last** client (this case 2). The connection with Client 1 stays established, but it's like Server 'forgets' about Client 1.  I do not want to broadcast, but I just want to know how can I `dos.writeUTF(msgout)` to e.g. the first Client? Here is my piece of code from the Server.

Static variables (i'm using Swing as GUI):

```
static DataOutputStream dos;
static DataInputStream dis;
static Vector<ClientHandler> ar = new Vector<>(); // Vector for active clients
static int i = 0; // Client counter
```

The piece from the main method where connection is settled:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket s;

while (true) {
    s = ss.accept();    
    dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    ClientHandler mtch = new ClientHandler(s, "Client" + (i+1), dis, dos);
    Thread t = new Thread(mtch);
    ar.add(mtch); // Add client to active clients
    t.start();
    i++;
}
```

I have made a method to send messages (when I click a button):

```
public void send() {
try {
    String msgout = "";
    msgout = txtChat.getText().trim();
    if (!msgout.equals("")) {
        dos.writeUTF(msgout); // Need to get specific here. How to write to Client's 1 DataInputStream?
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
       //
  }
}
```

ClientHandler class is found here https://pastebin.com/NWms7TfF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not good:

```
static DataOutputStream dos;
```

followed by:

```
dos.writeUTF(msgout);
```

You're creating a single static DataOutputStream field and then wondering why using this field only represents one output stream. First of all, you should get rid of the static fields, although this won't solve your problem (but it might help fix others). Instead if you want to write to a specific output stream, you need a way to get a reference to it. Consider creating a HashMap to hold your `ClientHandler` objects, and add them to the Map using whatever unique identifier you wish to use that would help you retrieve them, perhaps a clientName String field or a clientId String field (don't use numbers for id). And assuming that `ClientHandler` has a `getDos()` method that returns its output stream (if it doesn't have this then it should get one). Then you can get the ClientHandler from the Map when needed, extract its output Stream via `getDos()`, and then write to it.

Side note, it is not appropriate to post links to code bases. Instead please post all relevant code in your question.